# Return variable in function from method callback data in same function

Tags: javascript, function, callback, return

How do I return the latlon variable for codeAddress function.  return latlon doesn't work, probably because of scope but I am unsure how to make it work.

```
function codeAddress(addr) { 
       if (geocoder) { 
           geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addr}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latlon = results[0].geometry.location.c+","+results[0].geometry.location.b;  
                    } else {
                       alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                   }

       });
     }  
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return the result of `geocoder.geocode` from `codeAddress` since `geocoder.geocode` will return its result to the callback/closure you provide. You have to proceed using a callback given as an argument to your function `codeAddress`.

Returning anything from your callback given to `geocoder.geocode` back to `geocoder.geocode` will not make any sense in your application. You have to call some function in your application from the callback you provide to `geocoder.geocode`.

This is explained in [Geocoding Requests](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/v3/services.html#GeocodingRequests) section of the API.

Comment: Thanks I have ran up against this many times in jquery ajax callback and just wasn't thinking today.  Thanks for the brain boost.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable in the outer function, set it in the inner function and return it in the outer:

```
function codeAddress(addr) { 
  var returnCode = false;
  if (geocoder) { 
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addr}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var latlon = results[0].geometry.location.c+","+results[0].geometry.location.b;
        returnCode = true;
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }  
  return returnCode;
}
```

**NOTE: This will only work if the inner function is run right away!**

Comment: Which it might not do since geocoder.geocode might perform an asynchronous method invocation where the only way to return the result is through the callback provided.